# Swift array of protocols with associatedtype

Tags: swift, protocols

I have the first protocol

```
protocol Prot1
{

}
```

And the second:

```
protocol Prot2
{
    associatedtype P: Prot1

    func doSomething(param: P)
}
```

How can i make an array with the type Prot2?

I tried:

```
var myArray = [Prot2]()
```

But it gives me this error: **Protocol Prot2 can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements**

Is there any other way to make a template protocol?

**EDIT:**

Sorry if i am late, but i was testing the solutions.
As far as i understand the type-erase

```
AnyProt2<Prot1Type: Prot1>: Prot2
```

let me have a an array with

```
[AnyProt2<Prot1Class>]
```

but i was asking for an array that could contain all kinds of AnyProt2 something like:

```
[AnyProt2] or [AnyProt2<Prot1>]
```

I tried the second but it gives me:

> Using 'Prot1' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'Prot1' is not supported.

In my context Prot1 is Interval and Prot2 is a Event, so i wanted to have and array with different kinds of Events that could have different kinds of Intervals.
I also want to ask if it's possible to make Prot1 to extend Equatable and confirm the protocol in AnyProt2.

Comment: Any help for the update?

Answer (score 8):

Depending on your use case, you might get away with using generics, like so:

```
protocol Prot1 {
}

protocol Prot2 {
    associatedtype P: Prot1
    func doSomething(param: P)
}

class MyClass<T: Prot2> {
    var arr: [T] = []
}
```

But this solution pretty much defers the specifying of the concrete type implementing `Prot2` and making consumer of `MyClass` to deal with that.

Sounds like your case would require to use something called "type erasure". Unfortunately, I won't be able to explain it here, but here are some really great articles and even talks that helped me to understand the concept:

- https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-type-erasure/
- Video: https://realm.io/news/tryswift-gwendolyn-weston-type-erasure/
- http://krakendev.io/blog/generic-protocols-and-their-shortcomings
- http://robnapier.net/erasure
- https://realm.io/news/type-erased-wrappers-in-swift/